# Why an a -> b -> c function argument can accept a -> a type?

Tags: haskell

This compiles successfully:

```
test = f id
f :: (a -> b -> c) -> String
f g =  "test"
```

`id` has type `a -> a`, but `f` have a first argument of type `(a -> b -> c)`.

I think it should not compile. I cannot understand it.

Comment: Hint: what is the type of `id` in the expression `id not`?

Comment: i dont understand what you mean ~~

Comment: I mean, the type of `id` in the expression `id "hi there"` is `String -> String`, because `"hi there"` has type string, so that's what `a` gets instantiated to. The type of `not` is `Bool -> Bool`. So what is the type of `id` in the expression `id not`?

Comment: `a` can be a type as well, the `a` in `a -> a`, is *not* the same `a` as in `a -> b -> c`. `a -> b -> c` is short for `a -> (b -> c)`, so if you pass `id :: d -> d`, then, we know that `a ~ d ~ b -> c`

Comment: @user754458: If I want GHCi to answer a question like “What is the type of `id` in the expression `id not`”, I might phrase it as `:type \ (_ :: what) -> (id :: what) not`. Since `what` is a fresh type variable here, it won’t match any concrete type, so the compiler will report a type error saying that `what` doesn’t match the inferred type of the subexpression that I annotated, and it will print out that type for me in the error message. This uses the “scoped type variables” language flag (`:set -XScopedTypeVariables`).

Answer (score 7):

Because you can bind the uninstantiated variable. `f :: (a -> b -> c) -> String` says that for any 3 types a, b and c, f takes a function from a to b to c and returns string.

Its important to remeber that `f :: (a -> b -> c) -> String` is equivalent to `f :: (a -> (b -> c)) -> String` because of currying.

`id` takes any type, and returns that type.

So if we swap that in, `id` is returning `b -> c`, and taking `a`, so if `a` can be `b -> c` which it can as a can be any type, then this is fine.

Comment: f  :: (a -> (b -> c)) -> String, id :: a -> a, id :: a -> (b -> c)

id takes any type, and returns that type.
i think that a and b -> c it not same type.

Comment: @user754458 Why not? That is the whole point. In instancing f  by passing it id, you can add any restrictions to the types you like, so you can restrict a to be b -> c

Comment: @user754458 to match the types, the compiler solves the equation `a -> b -> c = x -> x` and finds that `x = a = (b -> c)`.

Comment: i am very stupid. i can understand it now.  you helped me a a lot. thanks a ton.

Comment: Minor terminology note: there are no free (type) variables here. The binders are implicit, but the language specification makes it unambiguous how to insert binders when there are none. The explicit versions, `id :: forall a. a -> a` and `f :: forall a b c. (a -> b -> c) -> String`, for which the signatures in the question are shorthand, make it more obvious that none of the variables are free.

Comment: @DanielWagner I've swapped free for unbound. Is that better?

Comment: @user1937198 No, free and unbound mean the same thing. Wording that's more consistent with the literature would be "Because you can instantiate the variable." I can't think of any relevant, correct adjective to attach to "variable".

Comment: @DanielWagner If the wording is can be instantiatated, then instantiatable or uninstantiated?

Comment: @user1937198 Yes, sure, I like that! Good thinking.

Answer (score 6):

Short version: it works because `id` can take and return functions -- and so can behave as if it were a two-argument function. Now for the long version.

`id` is a function that takes a value and returns it unchanged. Because it's so simple, it can do that for all kinds of different values -- `Int`s and `Bool`s and `String`s and lists and trees...

```
id :: Int -> Int
id :: Bool -> Bool
id :: String -> String
id :: [(b, c)] -> [(b, c)]
id :: Tree b -> Tree b
id :: (b -> c) -> (b -> c)
```

...and functions, why not!

`f` is a function that takes two-argument functions and ignores them. Because its handling of the function you give it is so simple, it can do that for all kinds of different two-argument functions -- addition, concatenation, pairing, ignoring, printing...

```
f :: (Int -> Int -> Int) -> String
f :: ([b] -> [b] -> [b]) -> String
f :: (b -> c -> (b, c)) -> String
f :: (b -> c -> b) -> String
f :: (Handle -> String -> IO ()) -> String
f :: ((b -> c) -> b -> c) -> String
```

...and the operation that takes a function and an argument and applies the one to the other, why not!

Ah, but two argument functions are really just one-argument functions that themselves return a function. So these two types are really just different spellings of the *same* type:

```
(b -> c) -> (b -> c)
(b -> c) -> b -> c
```

And, it turns out, the two behavior descriptions I gave for these two types also turn out to be the same. Recall they were:

1. A function that takes a function as an argument and returns it unchanged.
2. A function that takes a function as an argument, and an argument for that function, and applies one to the other.

I'll let you stew for a bit on why those turn out to be the same!

In any case, at this point it should be much more clear why this works. And, for the mechanical version of the answer, we can take these two types:

```
id :: a -> a
f :: (a -> b -> c) -> String
```

and make them fit together by choosing `a ~ b -> c` for both. (It is just a coincidence that the two instantiations of `a` are to the same type -- this is not generally the case when doing unification!) After instantiating `a` to `b -> c` in both type signatures, we get:

```
id :: (b -> c) -> b -> c
f :: ((b -> c) -> b -> c) -> String
```